# hot reload is not issue when i use MaterialApp.router

Tags: flutter, dart

When i use go router package, hot reload is always reset to initial page like hot restart. I removed MaterialApp.router. and then restart is working. I don't know how can i fix.
flutter version is 3.3.4.
go router version is 5.1.0.
flutter doctor is not issue.

my code is below.

```
class AppRouter {
  final LoginInfo loginInfo;
  AppRouter(this.loginInfo);

  late final router = GoRouter(
      debugLogDiagnostics: true,
      routerNeglect: true,
      redirect: (context, state) {
        print(':::: ${loginInfo.isLogin}');
        final bool? loggedIn = loginInfo.isLogin;
        final bool loggingIn = state.subloc == '/login';

        if (loggedIn == null) {
          return null;
        }
        if (!loggedIn) {
          return loggingIn ? null : '/login';
        }

        if (loggingIn) {
          return '/';
        }

        return null;
      },
      refreshListenable: loginInfo,
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: '/',
          builder: (context, state) {
            return const BottomNaviBar();
          },
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              name: 'statusCheck',
              path: 'statusCheck',
              builder: (context, state) {
                return const StatusCheckPage();
              },
            ),
        GoRoute(
          name: 'login',
          path: '/login',
          builder: (context, state) {
            return const LoginPage();
          },
        ),
      ]);
}
```

Comment: How do you use the loginInfo?

Comment: loginInfo is provider.

Comment: You can share loginInfo provider code and some logs?

Comment: `class LoginInfo with ChangeNotifier {
  final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  bool? _isLogin;
  String? _platform;
  bool? get isLogin => _isLogin;
  String? get platform => _platform;
  LoginInfo() {
    loginCheck();
  }
}`

Comment: `Future<void> loginCheck() async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _isLogin = prefs.getBool('loginToken');
    _platform = prefs.getString('platform');
    print(_isLogin);
    notifyListeners();
  }`

Comment: this class used root page to wrap MaterialApp widget.